# Combining Bash Script and Script Resources into One Executable

Tags: bash

When trying to execute a Bash script, it is often executed inside some directory, and requires access to local resources. I was wondering if there was a way to combine both the Bash script and the resources (everything else in the directory) into an executable, so that I would only need that executable stand-alone to execute the Bash script.

Comment: Why not use absolute paths in the script so that it can be run from anywhere?

Comment: What type of resources?  Text may be easily included as "here" documents (  << label....data .... label). Binary, would be another problem.

Comment: I concur with @ubfan1. What type of resources and how are they used? Does the shell script use them itself directly? Does it pass them to other programs? How (standard input redirection, command line argument…)? How would the resulting program “executable” be used?

Answer (score 2):

Self-extracting scripts are possible, and not uncommon. They are often used by installers. The idea is simple:

1. The top part of the script sets up the execution of the bottom
2. In the middle there is an `exit` command, to avoid executing the end part
3. The end part is a payload

Here's a concrete example. Create `script.sh` with this content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

me=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)/"$(basename "$0")"

cd "$(mktemp -d)"
tail -n +10 "$me" | tar zx
cat local.txt

exit
```

This corresponds to the top and middle part I mentioned earlier.
Essentially this does:

1. Extract the end part (line 10 and beyond) of this script itself into a temporary directory, using `tar`
2. Print the content of `local.txt`, which is expected in the temporary directory
3. Exit

This script is not complete, we need to add the end part, which is expected to be a zipped `tar`, containing a file named `local.txt`. Let's create that file first:

```
echo hello world > local.txt
```

And let's put that file in a `tar`, and append it at the end of the script:

```
tar zc local.txt >> script.sh
```

If you reopen `script.sh` in a text editor, you will see some gibberish at the end. That's binary data, the content of a zipped `tar` archive with `local.txt` in it. If you run this script, it will output `hello world`, from the embedded `local.txt` file that it unzips from itself.

You can use the same technique to create something meaningful and sophisticated.